# installing Radiant on DreamHost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dreamhost, radiant

I am attempting to install Radiant on DreamHost, and when I get to the point where I do this:

```
radiant mysitename
```

It starts to install, then I get this error

> /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55:
>   uninitialized constant
>   ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
>   (NameError)

Now one thing I think it might be is that DreamHost has me using Rails 3, is that the case?  If so, how can I run an older version?  I am stumped - thanks.

**Setup:**

- ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 3.0.7
- Gem 1.8.2
- Radiant 0.9.1

Comment: No offense, but it works for me, even with the Rails which are installed on dreamhost. Make sure you don't have anything under vendor/rails in your application. And yes, Radiant requires 2.3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by the combination of RubyGems > 1.6.0 and Rails < 2.3.11
You could fix this by downgrading to rubygems version 1.5.3

```
gem update --system 1.5.3
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is the soon to be released Radiant 1.0

Essentially: a recent version of Rubygems introduced a change that changed some things Rails depended on. This was fixed in a point release of Rails (say 2.3.9), but Radiant 0.9 was based on a version of Rails before that.

There are ways to patch your Rails/Radiant apps to get it [see my pull request on Github for this](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/pull/209#issuecomment-1198472)... which sometimes works (I've found issues with it over the last few days.

**However** I know that the Radiant core team wants to release a new version of Radiant today (May 18) or the next day. This will upgrade to the latest Rails 2.3 release, which solves the problem

Comment: This is fantastic news, I can wait :)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to step 7 under **Install RubyGems** in this [wiki](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/installing-on-dreamhost-using-ssh) it shows how to install an older version of Rails. Earlier in that section it also mentions checking for a different version number for Gem than the one you have listed.

Comment: I have installed the older version - I have even tried to uninstall all newer versions, but I still get 3.0.2...?

Comment: Hmmmm. So you followed the documented steps? How proficient are you with using a Unix (ie - Linux or OSX) based terminal? Just trying to get a grasp of your experience so I can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I have a good amount of experience with Linux - but I am no expert.  I run Ubuntu on a box at home and went through 2 Computer Science degrees (MS/BS) which was basically all *nix machines.

Comment: @naspinski Cool. Well since you have basic knowledge we can throw that out the window. Dreamhost also has a [wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Ruby_on_Rails#Quick_Start). Did you try that? Sorry I can't be of more help. If I had a Dreamhost account I could go in there and try the install myself. It also sucks because it doesn't sound like this is something they support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this HOWTO: https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Installing-on-Dreamhost-Using-SSH